# Recover data from bitlocker partition in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, bitlocker

I have one hard drive. It's partitioned into 4 partitions, one of them is encrypted by Windows 7 Bitlocker, then I used Acronis Disk Director to merge both partitions during the process PC power off now the encrypted partition and when I try to enter the partition I have a message to format it, the other partition seems to contain 20 MB but when I open it I found nothing.

all data in this partition is so important to me , so please if anyone can help me recover my data I will be thankful

Comment: why don't you accept more answers to your questions? People don't like to help one that just ask things but don't give feedback of what helped, what was the best answer, etc

Comment: This is when those data backups come in real handy.

Comment: The Bitlocker Repair tool is actually for Vista and Server 2008 only. If you installed this on Windows 7 I would like to know how, so I can repair my encrypted drive, where even Microsoft has not given a solution, but wants me to send it to a 3rd party company to recover at the price of $2700. Also Microsoft promotes that a bitlocker secured drive is protected from Data loss, Hackers, and Stolen data. Seems that is not the case as after all my reading I have found methods to get around encrypted drives, and the Data loss is actually a Microsoft issue, that has only been addressed for Vista and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the [bitlocker recovery tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928201)

> You can use this tool to help access encrypted data if the hard disk has been severely damaged. This tool can reconstruct critical parts of the drive and salvage recoverable data. A recovery password or recovery key is required to decrypt the data.

For Windows 7, Microsoft have some [advice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523219(WS.10).aspx)

> The BitLocker Repair Tool (Repair-bde) is a command-line tool included with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. This tool can be used to access encrypted data on a severely damaged hard disk if the drive was encrypted by using BitLocker Drive Encryption. Repair-bde can reconstruct critical parts of the drive and salvage recoverable data as long as a valid recovery password or recovery key is used to decrypt the data. The Repair-bde command-line tool is intended for use when the operating system does not start, or when you cannot start the BitLocker Recovery Console. If a drive has been physically damaged, it may not be recoverable.

---

This sort of experience does demonstrate the importance of making a daily backup of important data to an external hard disk or to another computer. It is probably worthwhile making occasional copies onto DVD and storing those in a separate building (in case of fire or burglary).